# vim - copy folds to a copied file

Tags: folding

Any way to copy folds to a copied file?

Example: file1 has several folds, now I create a new file `cp file2 newfile`. `newfile` doesn't have folds that I had created in vim, of course it won't as `cp` and `vim` are different commands.

Any way to copy folds of `file1` to `newfile`?

Comment: You might be interested in `:help mkview` and `:help loadview`

Comment: `mkview` and `loadview` are for saving and loading folds of one file. Here, my question is to copy fold of one file to other file.

Comment: `mkview` creates a file in `viewdir` which identifies the folds (among other things) of a specific view. What you can do is load this file from another view

Comment: I just recorded a quick demo: https://zorzi.wistia.com/medias/lyoa0jo8h4

Comment: cool. Thanks. Convert to answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:saveas` (less manipulations then with `:mkview/loadview`)

It will make a copy of your file and its view into a new file with its own view.
You original file and view will be left untouched.

```
:edit original.md
:saveas copy.md
```

The only downside is that if you have file marks (A-Z), they will be moved (not copied, moved) to your new file.

*Also answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71349298/6356206*